# How to clear one signal Push Notification programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications, onesignal

I used push notification in my app using One signal. I added an action button name: Clear id: clearNotific . I want when user click on this clear button in notification then this notification will remove. I can collect notification id and I am trying to use `notificationManager.cancel(not_id);`
But this is not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Create this class,

```
public class ApplicationNotificationReceive implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
@Override
public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
         OneSignal.cancelNotification(notification.androidNotificationId);
    }
}
}
```

In application class replace with this,

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ApplicationNotificationReceive())
            .init();
```

Comment: Yes i will but now i have only 1 reputation.